# Linear regression always results in the optimal linear model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

let's say I'm running a linear regression model via `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` for two independent variables X1 and X2 predicting Y.

Am I guaranteed that the result would be optimal / minimize the sum-of-squers-error, and other linear models like Perceptron or linear SVM will not results in better metric?

Now, lets say I'm defining a new variable X3 = X1 (a direct copy of the existing variable) and now I repeat the process of a linear regression, only this time with 3 input X variables.
will the answer to the previous question change?

Comment: No, except if you force the neural net to use the same model structure as the linear regression.

Comment: If you define optimality in terms of least-squares error, then minimising least squares (as traditional linear regression does) will give you the optimal model, at least on the calibration sample.  Ridge regression may give you a better least-squares error on out-of-sample data, as may other algorithms.  The question is "why do you want to define optimal in terms of least-squares error?"  If you are considering the SVM, that suggests that least-squares may not be a good criterion.

Comment: 1) Could you clarify what you mean by optimal? It sounds like you're exclusively interested in the squared prediction error. Is that right? 2) If so, do you mean the error within the training set, or the expected error when making predictions for new data? 3) There are multiple kinds of linear regression. Are you asking about ordinary least squares (OLS) in particular? That's probably the most common use of `sklearn.LinearRegression`, but it can do other things too. 4) Perceptrons and SVMs are for classification, not regression so there's no valid comparison.